# Minecraft runs smoothly on Windows but crashing in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: opengl, minecraft, mesa

Hi and according to the title it crashes and the error is

```
glfw error 65543: Failed to create context: GLXBadFBConfig.
Please update your drivers. (see aka.ms/minecraft for more instructions)
```

If any more information is required please comment me and i will provide it.

My inbuilt VGA controller:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
        Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
```

And I don't have any graphics card.

Comment: Please edit the question and post hardware specifications, especially graphics. The error is unusual but has something to do with graphics drivers.

Comment: @ChanganAuto sir I have edited it please review the question

Comment: Graphics and graphics drivers seem fine. The error is known after all (and Minecraft specific). Try the following suggestions: https://www.planetminecraft.com/blog/glfw-error-65543-glx-failed-to-create-context-glxbadfbconfig-solution/

Comment: @ChanganAuto Sir I will try

Comment: @ChanganAuto Sir it worked and thanks for your kind assistance. I am very ashamed of how to thank you and you may post your answer to get free reputation :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following information comes from this [Minecraft's blog tutorial](https://www.planetminecraft.com/blog/glfw-error-65543-glx-failed-to-create-context-glxbadfbconfig-solution/). The error has been around and a solution was found by the "expert nerd" Nachitus, all credits to this person.

Quoting:

> GLFW error 65543: GLX: Failed to create context: GLXBadFBConfig.
> Is an error that happens specially when you're trying to load Minecraft with Optifine in 1.17.1. The cause of this error is that this Optifine version needs OpenGL 4.3 to create a context apparently called "GLXBadFBConfig".
> (...) Yes, for some reason this error usually happens on Linux and not on Windows.

Workaround:

```
MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=4.3
```

to temporarily override the OpenGL version variable. Then run it with

```
MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=4.3 (your minecraft executable)
```

or if Java then

```
MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=4.3 java -jar (your minecraft executable)
```

The example given below is for the Fénix Launcher:

```
MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=4.3 java -jar LauncherFenix-Minecraft-v7.jar
```